# how to rename choice column options and see the changes in the workflows

Tags: workflow

I have a choice column in my document set and I have already written many workflows for each option. now I want to rename some of these options. how can I rename the column choices in one place and see the effect in the workflows too? is there a way to do this from sharepoint designer or  sharepoint site settings?

Comment: This should be possible to do directly on the list itself or in the contenttype. Have your tried doing this?

Comment: yes I have already tried it but it has no effect on the workflows!

Comment: Is the changes visible when you start a new workflow?

Comment: yes it is visible.

Comment: as an solution is it possible to define my choice options as A,B ,C and in a workflow set the A,B and C to different string variables? in this way whenever I need to change an option, I should only change that string variable.